# WSO Identity Server HA Cluster

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm posting this seeking help with WSO Identity Server Cluster configuration. I've been tasked to set up a WSO2 Identity Server cluster in a high availability configuration. I've successfully set up the stand alone identity servers. Which was not a problem. However, I'm having difficulty determining the correct documentation to follow at the WSO documentation web pages. I cannot locate the documentation for setting up a vanilla HA IS cluster. That is what I’m trying to locate. Another issue that I’m confused about is WSO2 IS and its cluster configuration types. At this link https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29918203 it states, “Worker/manager separation is not possible in the Identity Server and is not used as a typical scenario when deploying the Identity Server. See  here (https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+Identity+Server) for clustering the Identity Server.” The link directs me to the “Clustering Identity Server” document page. It contains two sections. The first section is “Clustering IS”. The last sections covers “Fronting the IS cluster with WSO2 ELB”. The section that I think I should follow would be the first section. Because I do not wish to have a load balancer configuration. However, the “Clustering IS” section of the document does not reference whether the configuration is for high availability. There doesn’t seem to be a specific document that focuses on WSO2 IS HA cluster configuration. So I’m here pleading for assistance in directing me towards the correct documentation to configure a WSO2 IS HA cluster. If anyone has experience configuring a WSO2 IS HA cluster and knows which documentation to follow, please send a reply. Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

From clustering (running multiple instance of WSO2IS), you can achieve the high availability and fail over.  But,  you need to front your cluster by a load balancer to distribute the load on each instance.  You can achieve the cluster configuration as above in the doc. Then you can configure some load balancer as well.  It can be any load balancer such as Apache HTTP, Nginx or some hardware LB.  You do not want to configure WSO2 ELB. You can find some [guide](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/04/10/load-balancing-for-identity-server-nodes-using-apache-http-server/) on using Apache server with WSO2IS cluster.